# Magento Import: min_sale_qty is ignored

Tags: php, magento, import, magento-1.7

Im using the [AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) Modul to import products into Magento. So far it works well with a lot of attibutes/configurations. The problem is that some attributes like `min_sale_qty` or `use_config_min_sale_qty` are simply ignored and have no effect at all. I set `use_config_min_sale_qty` to `0` so I thought it should work.

**Update**

It does work if I set `use_config_min_sale_qty = 0`, `min_sale_qty = 4` fix for the whole import. But I only have some products with `min_sale_qty > 1`. It looks like it uses the first value for the whole import.

Example product:

```
Array
(
    [sku] => 5409
    [_type] => simple
    [_attribute_set] => Default
    [_product_websites] => base
    [name] => Test
    [price] => 3
    [qty] => 1
    [is_in_stock] => 1
    [min_sale_qty] => 4
    [use_config_min_sale_qty] => 0
    (... some more)
)
```

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in the import modul (Magento Core).

\app\code\core\Mage\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\Product.php, Line 1609

Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::_saveStockItem()

$row was not initialised:

```
$row = array();
$row['product_id'] = $this->_newSku[$rowData[self::COL_SKU]]['entity_id'];
$row['stock_id'] = 1;
```

This bug is [fixed in Magento2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php#L1401) but not in 1.7.0.2 community version.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Just to add to this answer: if you're using AvS_FastSimpleImport the actual uninitlialized `$row` variable is here `\app\code\community\AvS\FastSimpleImport\Model\Import\Entity\Product.php` around line 1161.